# How do I use Unity drag handles?

Tags: unity, multi-touch, window-management, grab-handles

I saw on [this post](http://codearmada.com/2011/03/24/unity-has-love-handles) that Unity has touch enabled drag handles. How do I turn them on so I can use them with a mouse?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Unity multitouch grab handles plugin ships with Unity. It is activated by a three finger press on a touch screen. You can toggle it by repeatably tapping three fingers on your touchscreen.

You can use it with a mouse by toggling the plugin on and off. To ensure the plugin is enabled, do the following:

1. Start the *CompizConfig Setting Manager*: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to open the run dialog, type `ccsm`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (if that doesn't work, you probably need to install the package `compizconfig-settings-manager` first).
2. The grab handle plugin will only work correctly, if the *Png* plugin is enabled, so scroll down to the *Image Loading* section and make sure *Png* is ticked:

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [xrmb2.net](https://img.xrmb2.net/images/277713.png))</sub>
3. Now scroll further down to the *Uncategorized* section and tick the *Unity MT Grab Handles* plugin:

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [xrmb2.net](https://img.xrmb2.net/images/586129.png))</sub>
4. By default, there is no shortcut defined to initiate the handles, so click on the *Unity MT Grab Handles* button to configure the shortcut (and also the fade duration, if you like):

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [xrmb2.net](https://img.xrmb2.net/images/485094.png))</sub>
5. Next to *Toggle Handles* click on the *Disabled* button and tick the *Enable* checkbox:

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [xrmb2.net](https://img.xrmb2.net/images/481978.png))</sub>
6. Now click on *Grab key combination* and press the desired shortcut:

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [xrmb2.net](https://img.xrmb2.net/images/876147.png))</sub>
7. Confirm and close the *CompizConfig Setting Manager*. Now you should see the handles like in the picture in the question when using the shortcut you just defined.

Comment: I thought three-finger-tap was equivalent to middle click, which is paste? What happens if I have something in my clipboard and I three-finger-tap a window? Will it paste or will drag handles appear? or both? or neither? :D

Comment: it will do the drag handles right now (i think thats how utouch works)

Comment: @popey The middle click was moved to a 5 finger tap, as it turns out.