# What is this hidden Unity window-dragging feature I discovered on accident, and how do I reproduce it?

Tags: unity, windows, grab-handles

I was just idly mousing over folders in Nautilus on my laptop, when all of a sudden these window-dragging icons appeared and I was moving my window across the screen. Look at the screenshot to see what I mean.

[image]

What was that, and how do I turn it on again? Because that looked *really cool*. I tried, but couldn't get it to display again.

This is an unmodified Ubuntu 11.10 upgraded from Ubuntu 11.04, on a Toshiba Satellite A505. I was using the touchpad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the grab handles which make moving and resizing windows in Ubuntu easy.

You can produce this by middle clicking on a window. On a laptop this is usually done by one of the following methods depending on your trackpad / mouse.

1) Tapping / Clicking with three fingers and dragging if using a multi-touch trackpad.

2) Clicking With both the right and left mouse buttons at the same time and dragging.

3) Clicking with the middle mouse button if using an external mouse and dragging.

Really just anything that simulates a middle click and then a drag. It might vary depending on your configuration but one of those should work.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect that I'm using just a touchpad. I'm not sure of its full capabilities, but I do know I can do a single-tap for a left click, double-tap and drag to drag stuff the "usual" way, and tap with two fingers to simulate a right-click (most of the time, anyway). I could not get it to appear again with any of these options...is there a way I can view the configuration for my touchpad?

Comment: Ah, nevermind! Option 1 worked for me after a little practice. Now I have yet another way to show off Ubuntu to people! :D

Comment: Awesome :) Yeah it takes a bit to figure out exactly how to do the three-finger click, and it varies depending on how sensitive your trackpad is. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

In ccsm you can find unity mt grab handles. You can set up your shortcut there:

Configuration for the feature is found here:

- [How do I use Unity drag handles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31877/how-do-i-turn-on-unity-drag-handles)

[image]

Comment: Okay, but I don't have `ccsm` installed and I was still able to reveal this. There *has* to be a way to do this without extra configuration, though I'll keep this option in mind.