# What is this window overlay?

Tags: unity, compiz, touchpad, suspend, multi-touch

After waking up from suspend, I see these **half-transparent window handles**, but I don't know how to activate it.
Sometimes I can deactivate it by tapping the touchpad.

What is the function of this?
How to activate it?

[image: What is this?]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grab Handles appearing randomly, causes erratic mouse behavior](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71166/grab-handles-appearing-randomly-causes-erratic-mouse-behavior)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this hidden Unity window-dragging feature I discovered on accident, and how do I reproduce it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68910/what-is-this-hidden-unity-window-dragging-feature-i-discovered-on-accident-and)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the Unity Mt Grab Handles ( a compiz plugin). It gives you a move point (center) & resize handles.

To use - open the plugin  in ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager) & set a binding either for 'toogle handles' & or 'show handles'

It's value on a desktop/laptop install is questionable, there are easier ways to move & or resize windows & the plugin has been known to cause issues

If you have ccsm installed & wish to go directly to the plugin run

```
ccsm -p unitymtgrabhandles
```

Edit: if deciding to use, -  keep in mind that ccsm does not check for general keyboard binding conflicts so choose wisely