# Grab Handles appearing randomly, causes erratic mouse behavior 

Tags: 11.10, unity, trackpad, grab-handles

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 11.10 recently. Every so often, [Grab Handles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31877/how-do-i-turn-on-unity-drag-handles) will appear on the active window. Sometimes they simply disappear after a few seconds without causing me any problems.

Other times, the mouse appears already grabbing the window (like when you grab the center handle) and the mouse and the window will shake erratically for a few moments. In this case, I lose control over the mouse until the grab handles fade out a few seconds later. This occurs multiple times a day, maybe once every hour or two. The oddest thing about it is that I don't have Grab Handles enabled:

[image]

For reference, this is an Asus G53SW laptop with a Core i7, GeForce GTX 460M and 6 GB of RAM. Any ideas?

Comment: This should be reported at Launchpad as a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to fix this while I was trying to find a way to redefine 3 finger gestures.  I posted how I did it there: [How can I disable arbitrary default multitouch gestures in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57586/how-can-i-disable-arbitrary-default-multitouch-gestures-in-unity/90383#90383)

Let me know if that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 6):

It would seem to me, despite the response in the comments, that disabling the *Unity MT Grab Handles* option in `ccsm` should be able to turn these off, erratic mouse behavior notwithstanding.

**Steps to disable the grab handles:**

1. Install the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ccsm)[image: Install CompizConfig Settings Manager] (`ccsm`). You can do this either by clicking the provided link, or by opening a terminal and entering `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`, providing your password as needed.

   > WARNING: `ccsm` [has been known to break Compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it/80590#80590) if you are not careful! Try not to mess around in it too much.
2. Start CompizConfig Settings Manager. Look for a plugin called **Unity MT Grab Handles**. It should be at the very bottom when you scroll all the way down, under **Uncategorized**. Click its entry to enter its settings.[image: ccsm main screen]
3. Once in, find the checkbox labeled **Enable Unity MT Grab Handles** on the left side of the window under **Use This Plugin**. Uncheck it. This should be all you need to do; close `ccsm`.[image: Unity MT Grab Handles plugin screen]

If there is still an issue, then perhaps you should [file a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) if then restarting Compiz does not work (`compiz --replace`).

Comment: Sorry if my comments weren't clear enough. Disabling the plug-in does stop the Grab Handles from appearing.

Comment: @Doval Okay, I guess I misunderstood that part. But disabling the plugin does resolve your issue, correct? (I'd still post the erratic trackpad behavior as a separate question or a bug, since that's a bit more hardware-related.)

Comment: Right. The bit about the windows getting grabbed and moved is likely being triggered the same way as the Grab Handles were, since there's supposed to be a 3-finger gesture for moving windows: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch I'll probably post a separate question soon to address that issue.