# What are the orange circles appearing at the corners of my windows in Unity?

Tags: unity, laptop, touchpad, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use Unity drag handles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31877/how-do-i-use-unity-drag-handles)
>   [What is this hidden Unity window-dragging feature I discovered on accident, and how do I reproduce it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68910/what-is-this-hidden-unity-window-dragging-feature-i-discovered-on-accident-and)

Every so often when I am moving a window (using my laptop touchpad) orange circles (with arrows inside) appear at the corners and midpoints of the window. I think that they're for resizing, but all that happens is that the window moves with my cursor.

How am I triggering this? How can I stop triggering this? What are they supposed to be for?

[image: Example of orange circle things]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those orange circles are the Unity Grab Handles, a Compiz plugin designed to make resizing and moving easier with touchscreens or touchpads. By default, it is triggered by a three-finger tap over the window.

In the accepted answer of this question:

[How do I use Unity drag handles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31877/how-do-i-use-unity-drag-handles)

there is a very detailed guide to configure the handles. Since you just want to get rid of them, you only need to uncheck the plugin itself.

Comment: But where is this binding configured? The drag handles plugin itself does not contain any mouse binding configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it's a compiz plugin, that allow you to resize or drag a window with some orange arrows.