# Which is the (special) shortcut for move windows?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn on Unity drag handles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31877/how-do-i-turn-on-unity-drag-handles)

Some times (using only the touchpad laptop) a special controls appears for move the current window. Please, see this screenshot before reply:
[image: screenshot]

Which is this shortcut? I can't reproduce it!

Thanks in advance!! :)