# Tapping ALT brings up love handles, not the HUD

Tags: unity, multi-touch, hud

Just upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and wanted to test out some of the new keyboard shortcuts.

I probably have some config files sitting around from my 11.10 install, in particular I think I may have set ALT to bring up [love handles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31877/how-do-i-use-unity-drag-handles) on my windows so I could resize them easier when using my trackpad on my laptop.

Now it seems that the HUD has been assigned to tap ALT (at least according to the shortcut cheat sheet when I long press on SUPER) but when I tap alt all I get is love handles on my focused window.

Don't get me wrong, the [love handles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31877/how-do-i-use-unity-drag-handles) are excellent and I'd like to keep one of my keys as a shortcut to bringing them up to resize windows, but I would like to try out the HUD as well... where can I go to reset these keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: the link you have give explains how to change the shortcut for the "handles" - so I presume you have set "alt" as this shortcut.  Perhaps you need to reassign this shortcut as described in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut -> Launchers* we can assign any another key for the HUD:

[image]

Comment: this worked wonders for me! 
changed my HUD key to the tilde and loving the new way to interact with menus... thank you very much!